# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature while Running protractor e2e

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, typescript2.0

I'm working with an angular2 app where we have setup protractor for e2e testing, but unable to run e2e test cases with protractor and getting following error

```
e2e/app/framework/element-functions.ts(43,29): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
e2e/app/framework/wait-functions.ts(45,18): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<{}> | Condition<{}> | ((driver: WebDriver) => {})'.
Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(driver: WebDriver) => {}'.
Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(driver: WebDriver): {}'
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/angular_wait_barrier.d.ts(43,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/blockingproxy.d.ts(40,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(11,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(18,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(19,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/highlight_delay_barrier.d.ts(17,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(14,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(21,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(29,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(37,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/webdriver_proxy.d.ts(14,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/webdriver_proxy.d.ts(23,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(31,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(48,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(62,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(76,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(94,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

Environment : windows 10 (64bit)
Node: 6.11.0
Npm: 3.8.6
Protractor: 5.1.2
webdriver: 2.53.33
chromedriver: 2.30
TypeScript: 2.4.1

I've searched the internet but couldn't found a useful solution for this. Anything do I need to change to get this working ?

Comment: looks like some TypeScript parsing errors, can you add your `element-functions.ts` and `wait-functions.ts` files here

Comment: @wswebcreation I've updated question with files.

Comment: What do you want to do with `expectElementCount`?  Looks like that method is making it break (must say my tslinter is also pissed about all the other warnings, but those are less breaking) and I can't seem to figure out what the method should do. I also don't know if the `element-functions.ts` is a page object or something, but it is advices to prevent using expects in other files then your spec files